# How to add api key in the given URL?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to add API key in the given Angular Service, after compilation, it is showing %22 in the API URL. Can anyone please help how to send the correct API request?

```
async getCurrencies() {
    this.formatValidTimePeriod()
    this.statusService.sendStatus('updateStarted')
    let result = new Promise<void>(async (resolve, reject)=> {
    let datePeriodURLString = this.formatDatePeriodURLString()
     // console.log(this.datePeriod)
      await this.HTTPReq("GET",this.exchangeAPI,`${datePeriodURLString}"access_key="${this.key}base=${this.baseCurrency.active}`).then((res)=>{
       let rates=res.rates
        if (this.baseCurrency.dropDownList.length < 1) {
          this.setCurrencyDropDownList(rates)
        }
        if (!this.currencies.selected.active) {
          this.currencies.list = rates;
        } else {
         this.setPricesForSelectedCurrency(rates)
        }
        resolve()
        this.statusService.sendStatus('updateFinished')
      })

    });
    return result
  }
```

Comment: Please share your code, don't use images.

Comment: I think you have to remove the two " (quotes) from the URL. So "access_key" becomes access_key (without quotes)

Comment: I imagine you need add the API key to the header. If is for all your calls, use an interceptor. Is very similar to add a authToken like show the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#setting-default-headers) -only use some like: `req.headers.set('API_KEY, your-api-key)`-